# In ios 6 project, using ARC, is it safe to return from function NSDictionary created inside function?

Tags: ios, ios6

In ios 6 project, using ARC, is it safe to return from function NSDictionary created inside function ?
NSDictionary is required by AFHTTPClient to send parameters and I have nested blocks ( I hopes that is right way to send second request only if first was successful) for sending ( I first upload image of survey and if that was successful I upload answers in nested block). This requires to function be very long so I thought to create function which collect parameters  and returns NSDictionary to be more readable.( I am totally new to ios, so apologize if question no makes sense)

Comment: Do you have any example code to show? It would help me understand your question better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is common and expected. You should read over [Acquire Foundational Programming Skills](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/chapters/AcquireBasicProgrammingSkills/AcquireBasicSkills/AcquireBasicSkills.html) to make sure you have a basic understanding of Objective-C object models before proceeding.